# Dropdown does not appear

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have a problem with my theme. When I am using a registered account, the dropdown does not appear, the white space remains.
I am attaching the photo:
[image]

I tried the original LUMA theme, and it appears.
But when I enable the theme I bought gives me this error, unfortunately the assistance has expired and I can't ask for help directly.
What could the use be?

[image]

Comment: we can't provide support for third party software. especially with the information you provided